# Cross compiling Qt 5

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, cross-compiling

When cross compiling Qt 5.1 (arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7), what executables are not cross compiled (qmake, moc, bootstrap, etc.)?

After reviewing and running the Qt 5 build process, moc and boostrap are getting cross-compiled, which I think is causing a build error...

Comment: FYI: have you taken a look at http://buildroot.uclibc.org/? The project already provides Qt 5.0.2 and patches for Qt 5.1.1 were already posted and are being reworked.

Comment: Note there's `-platform` and `-xplatform`, to specify host and target platforms separately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When cross compiling Qt 5.1 (arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7), what executables are not cross compiled (qmake, moc, bootstrap, etc.)?

The "host" tools, basically:

- qmake (qbs in the future)
- moc
- uic
- qdoc
- rcc

Comment: Thanks. My build error was caused because I still had CC, CPP, LD, etc. variables defined for cross compiling, which was also defined in mkspec. Once I unset those variable the build worked.