# How can we cross compile qmake?

Tags: cross-compiling, qmake, moc, rcc, uic

When qt5 (5.9.2) is cross-compiled, the [qmake/moc/rcc/uic tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041157/cross-compiling-qt-5) are generated for the host machine. Is it possible to generate (cross-compile) them for the target device?

Thanks.